# Crystal Report multiple pages on one page

Tags: crystal-reports, report

How to create multiple pages on one page in crystal report just like on the image below?

[image]

Comment: I think you can use sub-reports concept  to achieve this requirements

Comment: i tried to use format with multiple columns. almost got it. but the problem is the sizing. i need to set fixed size per item

Comment: @BEN SEBASTIAN. thanks for ur reply. i got it now. i use subreport. thanks you so much

Comment: ok then I can make  it as a post , it may help some one in future . could you  please vote once I comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your requirement is to embedded multiple pages in the single page .

Sub-Reports are the way to achieve this . YOU CAN DESIGN MULTIPLE pages using sub reports  (each page in each sub reports). Once designed you can embedded it into the main/required page